How do I test a fluorescent light fixture for power?
I want to remove a fluorescent fixture which has failed. I've tried changing the tube with a brand new one but it won't light so I'm assuming the ballast failed. Rather than replacing the ballast, I want to remove the fluorescent fixture entirely and run the wire for the fixture into a new electrical box with a duplex receptacle that I plan to wire in. Then, I'll plug an LED fixture into the outlet. In order to do all that, I need to figure out which circuit breaker the fixture is on.
I'm having trouble with that. I bought a Klein No-Contact Circuit Tester (50-1000 amps) but it registers power in the wire that runs into the fixture regardless of whether the switch that activates the fixture is on or off. I have no idea why. The switch and fixture have been there and have worked together perfectly for at least 50 years with only a few tube changes over the years.
I don't know if I'm using the Klein tester incorrectly or if there is something else that explains this situation, like the switch failing.
In any case, I still need to figure out how to test the fixture for when it is getting power so that I can figure out which breaker it's on.
I have a multimeter but I'm not sure how to use it for this purpose. I don't know which range to set the meter for - I'm in Canada and it's a 120 volt circuit - and I don't know where to put the probes in the "tombstones" on the fixture (the bulb has been removed).
I'd appreciate some guidance with this problem :-)
Answers to comments:
I don't have enough "reputation" to answer in the comments so I'll answer here.
@JACK - If I'm going to turn off all the breakers anyway, then I might just as well disconnect the old fixture and wire up the new receptacle while all the power is out (using my handy headlamp to see everything). That would seem to be simpler that doing what you're describing. I had hoped there was a simple way to use the multimeter (or the Klein tester) for my purpose.
Unfortunately, I can't see the comment added to Jack's comment when in Edit mode so forgive me for not knowing your name right now. You're absolutely right, I said 15-1000 amps when I should have said 50-1000 volts. I don't take offense/offence at your pointing that out; it was just me being too lazy to look up the specs of the tester and using the wrong term. Honestly, I'm not sure which spelling of offense/offence I should be using; we are supposed to use British spellings here - "colour" rather than "color" etc. - but lots of people use American spellings and I'm darned if I can remember whether "offense" is the British or American spelling :-)

Do fluorescents no long have starters—a little canister with 2 prongs, IIRC?

@Huesmann The last fluorescent fixture I saw with a starter was manufactured over 30 years ago. Starters are only needed for old "magnetic"  ballasts, but newer "electronic" ballasts do not require them.

Shows how many fluorescent lights I've changed in 30 years.

OK, To play is safe, turn off the main breaker in your panel. Then remove the connectors for the feed wires to the ballast, probably a black wire and white wire and separate them. Turn the breaker back on. Take the probes from your multi meter and carefully test the feed wires. You should be getting 120 volts with the switch in the "on" position. Now have someone turn off each breaker one at a time, until you see the voltage on your multi meter drop to zero. The breaker that drops the voltage to zero is the one you're looking for. Test it a few more times just for safety.

Just a safety related quibble on an otherwise excellent answer. An OP who doesn't know how to use a multimeter for this and confuses amps with volts is unlikely to be able to positively distinguish a 120V breaker from a 120V MWBC breaker that looks just like a 240V breaker. Best to turn off the main breaker while disconnecting the supply wires to the fluorescent fixture. (And no offense to the OP, or is it offence in Canada? ;-)

@MTA  Another excellent comment. I edited it into my answer.

Henry, to give a possible explanation to your non-contact tester detecting voltage whether the switch is on or off, this could happen if the wall switch is interrupting the neutral wire instead of the hot wire. This is contrary to code in the U.S. and presumably in Canada too because it is unsafe. It would leave some of the tombstone contact points live when it appears that the fixture is powered down, and that could cause a shock while changing a bulb.
